# How do I move a Ruby on Rails application, which uses a MySQL database, to a new server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new with Ruby on Rails. I have been using the Lynda tutorials. I finally have an application running on a Linux Box (using MySQL instead of SQLite). I am trying to do some testing locally in my Mac OS X but I was wondering what is the best way to load my database and application in my computer?

Of note is that my friend apparently added the initial data using a script which in called "sql_db_data" and it appears in the Script folder of my application.

After that I added more data using Rails console....

From what I read there are many ways of adding data to your rails application and now I am a bit confused. I was thinking I could just use rake db:schema:dump and run the migrations, but that would not contain the data. I don't mind losing the data I inserted through Rails Console since I should be able to insert again at some point. I guess I am trying to do damage control I figure what is the best way to approach this.

I guess I have multiple misconceptions/misunderstanding on how this is supposed to work, then again I am just learning RoR so any help is more than welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

`rake db:schema:load` Can be used the first time you want to put information from an existing db into a system as it creates tables and columns within the (existing) database using info from `schema.rb`.

Comment: So db:schema:dump (dumps your database content into schema file) while db:schema:load ( loads schema file to a database)?

Comment: As far as I can see, it drops your database and re-creates it based on your db/schema.rb file so you should always keep you schema.rb file up to date and under version control.

Comment: Thanks I was able to do db:schema:load, but that only creates the models for me, just like if I was running migrations right? Unfortunately, my application is now loaded but there is no data.

Comment: I would recommend setting up some seed data if you are only using test data between your projects, it means you wont have to manually enter data into projects. have a look at this link to see how to create some seed data https://github.com/mauricio/sunspot_tutorial/blob/master/db/seeds.rb Once you have this created you can run rake db:seed to create this data within the database. If you are doing this process again run rake db:setup to run a schema load and to seed the database.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at the "taps" gem which allows you to do DB-independent dumps and loads (Heroku db:push and db:pull use it).